# What is the relationship between windows 8 store app and windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-8

I really get lost for the relationship between windows 8 store app and windows phone 8 app.

Anyone could tell me?

w8 store app>wp8 app   OR    w8 store app=wp8 app?

what is the accurate definition of "windows 8 store app"?

web app?windows app?mobile app?  or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Windows Store Application` is **not same as** `Windows Phone 8 Application`, they are totally different (in terms of UI and other backend api's). `Windows Store Application` run on `Windows RT` and `Windows 8` while `Windows Phone 8` applications only run on `Windows Phone 8`.

Only similarity in Windows Phone 8 and Windows8 / Windows RT is that they have a same Kernel.

Comment: could the windows store app be construed as "app runs on pc and tablet"

Comment: Windows Store app will run on WinRT and Windows 8 devices.

Comment: Edited because Windows RT is not the same as WinRT.  Thanks Microsoft for confusing names.

Answer (score 0):

This [page][1] puts it well: "the truth is that they’re similar but different".

http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows-phone-8/windows-phone-8-notes-sdk-143827